# Winsock2 recv() hook into a remote process

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hook, recv, winsock2

I was trying to hook a custom recv() winsock2.0 method to a remote process, so that my function executes instead of the one in the process, i have been googling this and i found some really good example, but they lack description

```
typedef (WINAPI * WSAREC)( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags ) = recv;
```

Now my question is, what does this mean, or does, is this some sort of a pointer to the real recv() function?

And then the other piece of code for the custom function

```
int WINAPI Cus_Recv( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags ) 
{
    printf("Intercepted a packet");

    return WSAREC( s, buf, len, flags ); // <- What is this?
}
```

Sorry if these questions sound really basic, i only started learning 2 or 3 weeks ago.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where did you find such an example ?

the first line tries to define a new type WSAREC, which is a pointer to a function having the same signature as `recv()`. unfortunately, it is also trying to declare a variable of this type to store the address of the `recv()` function. the typedef is wrong since the function is lacking a return type. so it does not compile under Visual Studio 2003.

you may have more luck using:

```
int (WINAPI * WSAREC)( SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags ) = &recv;
```

which declares only a variable of type "pointer to function", which stores the address of the `recv()`.

now the second snippet is a function which has the same signature as the `recv()`function, which prints a message, then calls the original `recv()` through the function pointer declared above.

the code here only shows how to call a function through a pointer: it does not replace anything in the current process.

also, i am not sure you can interfere with another process and replace one function at your will. it would be a great threat to the security of the system. but why would you do that in the first place ??

Comment: I am trying to receive some packets from an online game, for creating a gameguard..
however this code compiles, and works perfectly, replacing the function was no breach of security, i used API hooking to detour( the missing code ) the function in the original process that receives the packets.
My question was solely about the concept, and how does it work, thanks for your answer anyway.